# Accessing Microsoft SQL Server remotely

Tags: sql-server

I am very naive to Microsoft SQL Server and SQL in general so excuse my ignorance.

We have this Microsoft SQL Server where we store our data from monitoring software. I need to run some queries and need to take a look at some data. Is there any way I don't have to remote into SQL Server to run these select queries?

Some sort of portal or light software I can download which connects to SQL Server and lets me do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use the SQL Server Management Studio. It can be downloaded separately.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx

Answer (score 0):

All you need is SQL Management Studio. You can download it using this link: [SQL Server 2014 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299). Please be sure to check the details to know the packages to select. Make sure to get the management studio checked.

If you need help using the management studio, this can help you: [SQL Management Studio Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934498.aspx)